# Asigning event to data loaded from external source

Tags: jquery, tooltip, mouseover

I am trying to put tooltip toa table that is loaded via ajax and I have this:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "tr", function(){
    $(this).tooltip({
        animation: true,
        title: "Data CRM",
        placement: "bottom"
    });
});
```

It works only after i hover few elements. Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: can you create some fiddle

Comment: What are that few elements? Be more specific..!

Comment: As you can see I assign the function to all table rows. So, 'few elements' = few table rows.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you set an mouseover event handler on "document tr" that initiates your tooltip plugin.

Is this your opinion? If not you can use jQuery's .ready() to load your plugin when the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).tooltip({
        animation: true,
        title: "Data CRM",
        placement: "bottom"
    });
});
```

If there is a reason your'e doing so...
you could also trigger the hover-event on specific elements by [jQuery.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) :

```
$('tr').trigger('mouseover');
```